# Как регулировать длину и ширину полосы прокрутки в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Как регулировать длину и ширину полосы прокрутки scrollbar в Tkinter? Например, пользователь вводит координаты полосы прокрутки, её длину и ширину. В ответ получает в окне Tk() полосу прокрутки с указанными параметрами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию ширина скролбара равна 16 пикселям, при желании ее можно задать через свойство `width`  при через конфиг, например 8 и 32 пикселя как на скриншотах ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview, width=32)
```

Длина скролбара будет зависеть от высоты/ширины контейнера если указано свойство `fill`.

Но высоту и относительное расположение можно подгонять параметрами

- **ipadx**: устанавливает отступ содержимого виджета от его границы по горизонтали.
- **ipady**: устанавливают отступ содержимого виджета от его границы по вертикали.
- **padx**: устанавливает отступ виджета от границ контейнера по горизонтали.
- **pady**: устанавливает отступ виджета от границ контейнера по вертикали

Например тут указана высота 40 и отступ от края 10 (по факту вдвое меньше):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=40, padx=10
```

так же значения можно передавать в виде списков, задавая левый/верхний и правый/нижний отступы одновременно, например

```
padx=[20, 60]
```